# c++ template: 'Instantiation of variable required here, but no definition is available'

Tags: c++, templates

I created a matrix template class for a matrix of type `T`. I get a linker error and a warning which says: `Instantiation of variable 'ndmatrix<unsigned int>::Subscriptable::_data' required here, but no definition is available`.

The template is defined in a separate header:

```
ndmatrix.h:
```

```cpp
#ifndef ndmatrix_h
#define ndmatrix_h
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

//Generic matrix class to hold the table levels of type T
template<class T>
class ndmatrix{

public:

    size_t R; //rows
    size_t C; //cols

    //Hack to use [][] operator on std::vector
    class Subscriptable{
    public:

        //Default constructor
        Subscriptable(){};

        Subscriptable(int idx, size_t R, size_t C) : _idx(idx), _R(R), _C(C) {
            for (int i = 0; i<_C*_R; i++) {
                _data.push_back(0);
            }
        };

        Subscriptable setIdx(int i){
            this->_idx = i;
            return *this;
        }

        //This is [] operator for ndmatrix::Subscriptable
        T operator[](int index) {
            return _data[_C *_idx + index];
        }

        auto addElement(T e, int i, int j){
            return _data.insert( _data.begin() + _C*i + j, e);
        };

        auto data() { return _data; };
    private:
        size_t _R; //rows
        size_t _C; //cols
        int _idx;
        static std::vector<T> _data; <== Warning: Instantiation of variable 'ndmatrix<unsigned int>::Subscriptable::_data' required here, but no definition is available.
    };

    Subscriptable _s;

    //This is [] operator for ndmatrix
    Subscriptable operator[](int idx){
        return _s.setIdx(idx);
    };

    //Constructors
    ndmatrix();
    ndmatrix(int __C, int __R);

    //Member functions
    void addRow(std::vector<T> row);
    void print_to_console( std::function<void(T)> printer ); //printer is used to print one element of type T to the console.
};

template <class T>
ndmatrix<T>::ndmatrix(){
    _s = Subscriptable();
};

template <class T>
ndmatrix<T>::ndmatrix(int __C, int __R){
    _s = Subscriptable();
    for (int i=0; i<__C*__R; i++) {
        _s.push_back(0);
    }
};

template <class T>
void ndmatrix<T>::addRow(std::vector<T> row){
    this->_s.data().insert( _s.data().end() , row.begin(), row.end() );
};

template <class T>
void ndmatrix<T>::print_to_console( std::function<void(T)>printer ) {
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++){
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (int j=0; j<C; j++) {
            printer( (*this)[i][j] );
        }
    }
}

#endif /* ndmatrix_h */
```

Then I try to use this in `main.cpp:`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "ndmatrix.h"

typedef unsigned int level_t;


//Read table of levels from file into a matrix
void read_matrix(ndmatrix<level_t>* const mat, const char* filename){
    std::ifstream fileInput(filename);

    int rows = 0;
    while (fileInput) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(fileInput, line, '\n');

        std::stringstream strstream(line);
        std::vector<level_t> row;
        level_t level;
        int cols=0;
        while ( strstream >> level ) {
            row.push_back(level);
            cols++;
        }

        mat->addRow(row);
        rows++;

        mat->C = cols;
        mat->R = rows;

        //debug
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //tests
    ndmatrix<level_t> matrix;
    read_matrix(&matrix, "table.dat");

    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to build I get the warning above, and a linker error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've wrote a declaration of static member variable `_data`, but skipped definition.

```c++
template< typename T > typename ::std::vector< T > ndmatrix< T >::Subscriptable::_data;
```

Update: with C++17 it became possible to use `inline` static variables that can be initialized in-class and don't require separate definition outside of the class:

```
static inline std::vector<T> _data{};
```

Comment: If I add `template< typename T > typename ::std::vector< T > ndmatrix< T >:: Subscriptable ::_data;` then it works. (You forgot ::Subscriptable :) ). But I really do not understand, why do I need this?

Comment: You need this because class definition can only contain static variable declarations (except for const enum or const integral). And in order to use this variable you need to place definition somewhere outside of class scope. These rules are quite weird.